# Is it possible to set default options for vue.draggable?

Tags: vue.draggable

I was wondering if it is possible to set default options for Vue.draggable? Currently I find I need to keep supply the options for each draggable when some (like the handle and scroll sensitivity) would be better set globally.

```
%draggable{ 'v-model': 'values', '@change': 'move', ':options': '{handle: ".handle", scrollSensitivity: 80}', 'element': 'tbody' }
```

Excuse the HAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, You can use a store to keep the default parameters and reuse them in diferent components.
Note that starting with version 2.19 the syntax is:

```
v-bind="{handle: '.handle', scrollSensitivity: 80}"
```

Or

```
handle=".handle" :scrollSensitivity="80"
```